# Intellij printing code for review

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I recently switched from eclipse to Intellij IDEA 13. When I attempt to print my class the result is 92,424 pages of code.

I created a new barebones project a as below to test:

```
package com.censoredplant.HelloWorld;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;

        public class MyActivity extends Activity {
        /**
        * Called when the activity is first created.
        */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to print the above class by selecting FILE> PRINT> and then selecting the  "File Filename" radio button. The result is 92,424 pages of code.

Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this with a similarly small class. I didn't want to waste paper, so I printed it to PDF -- it was just a single page.

Comment: Just printed a small interface from IntelliJ 12 and got it on one page in portrait mode.  Something else is wrong.

Comment: Are you running the latest version? I'm on 13.01

Comment: Why are you printing for review when you could be using the reVu feature?

Comment: Just started using this yesterday. I like to print code so I can write notes on it.

Comment: What platform? I can't reproduce this. That said, I'd consider changing your code review workflow anyway, particularly if it's with a team.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an issue in the reporting of the total pages to the print dialog. I also get a high number, but when I print, it is only 2 pages. Try doing a print to file/PDF/XPS or such as a test.

Comment: No need, the moment the windows print dialg appears it show the page range as 1 - 9999.